# C# - Values in an object's array being overwritten when writing to a different array

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

In a program I'm writing, I'm parsing color data from a binary file, and adding the data into an array of Frame objects (my own class). However, starting on the 75th iteration of the main `for` loop, writing to a temporary color array to later add into the next Frame overwrites some existing colors in the array of Frames.

This is the `for` loop that writes to the temporary color array:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    if (Utils.GetBit(bitMask, 15 - i))
    {
        ushort stC = 0;
        stC |= Convert.ToUInt16(byteArray[byteIndex++] << 8);
        stC |= Convert.ToUInt16(byteArray[byteIndex++]);
        tcolors[i] = Utils.ST2RGB(stC); //converts Atari ST color to ARGB. when this runs on the 75th iteration of the main for loop, it starts overwriting existing color data in the Frame array
    }
}
```

where `Utils.ST2RGB` is

```cs
public static Color ST2RGB(ushort stC)
{
    try
    {
        byte blue = Convert.ToByte(((stC & 0x007) & 0xff) << 5);
        byte green = Convert.ToByte((((stC & 0x070) >> 4) & 0xff) << 5);
        byte red = Convert.ToByte((((stC & 0x700) >> 8) & 0xff) << 5);

        return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
    }
    catch
    {
        return Color.Black;
    }
}
```

And this is the code that adds the temporary values into a new Frame for an array:

```cs
Frame tmpFrame = new Frame();
tmpFrame.clearScreen = tclearScreen;
tmpFrame.colorIndex = tcolorIndex;
tmpFrame.colors = tcolors; // <-------
tmpFrame.hasPalette = thasPalette;
tmpFrame.isIndexed = tisIndexed;
tmpFrame.numOfPolys = tnumOfPolys;
tmpFrame.polygonVerts = tpolygonVerts;
tmpFrame.vertexID = tvertexID;
tmpFrame.vertices = tvertices;
frames[f] = tmpFrame; //'f' is the main for loop iterator
```

I'll also include some debugging data.

The first Frame's color data on the first main for loop iteration:
[image: The first Frame's color data on the first main for loop iteration.]

The first Frame's color data after the 75th main for loop iteration:
[image: The first Frame's color data after the 75th main for loop iteration.]

The first Frame's color data on the 200th main for loop iteration:
[image: The first Frame's color data on the 200th main for loop iteration.]

At first, the temporary variables and arrays just had the same names as the ones in the Frame class, so I assumed that was the problem, and added a `t` to the beginning of the temporary variables. But that didn't change anything.

I am extremely confused, as this is not supposed to be happening. Any tips or ideas as to why?

Comment: What is the definition of `Utils.ST2RGB`?

Comment: [This.](https://pastebin.com/7QtvcQsV) It converts Atari ST color data into System.Drawing.Color.

Comment: Do you make a new colors array for every frame? If you assign the same temp colors array to every frame and then change the contents of the array, every frame will see the color array changing because they all point to the same single instance of the array object. An array is an object (ref type) even if it's  full of primitives (value types)

Comment: I didn't make a new array for every frame, as the array is only updated when the flag is set to. However, I did use Array.Copy instead of just using an =, and it works perfectly now. Thanks for giving me the tip!